# Spilt string and match end of string with enum values

Tags: java, regex

I have one string which i need to divide into two parts using regex

```
String string = "2pbhk";
```

This string i need to divide into `2p` and `bhk`

More over second part should always be `bhk` or `rk`, as strings can be one of `1bhk`, `5pbhk` etc

I have tried

```
String pattern = ([^-])([\\D]*);
```

Comment: What are the rules of splitting? Why do you want to have `2p` and `bhk`?

Comment: last part should be one of bhk or rk ... if my input is "5pbhk" then it should split as "5p" and "bhk".. if input is "1bhk" then it should split as "1" and "bhk"

Comment: Then use `indexOf` instead. Regex is not what you need here.

Comment: 2p stands for 2+ and bhk is needed as it should validate input .. no other values are accepted other then bhk or rk .. this are enums in my java app

Comment: @lampdev: Something like [this](https://ideone.com/bjQgg4)?

Comment: Can u please give an example for indexOf ,,, as i am new to java

Comment: @stribizhev ... ya exactly.. how can assign it to variable somethis like String[] args = Arrays.toString("5pbhk".split("(?=rk|bhk)"));

Comment: @lampdev: Please see my answer for more details.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regex `"(?=bhk|rk)"` with split.

```
str.split("(?=bhk|rk)");
```

This will split it if there is one of `bhk` or `rk`.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
(.*)(bhk|rk)
```

First capture holds the "number" part, and the second bhk OR rk.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
String string = "2pbhk";
String first_part, second_part = null;
if(string.contains("bhk")){
first_part = string.substring(0, string.indexOf("bhk"));
second_part = "bhk";
}
else if(string.contains("rk")){
first_part = string.substring(0, string.indexOf("rk"));
second_part = "rk";
}
```

Try the above once, not using *regex* but should work.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are looking to split strings that *end with* `rk` or `bhk` but not necessarily at the end of the string (i.e. at the word boundaries), you need to use a regex with `\\b`:

```
String[] arr = "5ddddddpbhk".split("(?=(?:rk|bhk)\\b)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

If you want to allow splitting inside a longer string, remove the `\\b`.

If you only split individual words, use `$` instead of `\\b` (i.e. end of string):

```
(?=(?:rk|bhk)$)
```

Here is my [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/bjQgg4)

Comment: I have updated my demo, please check, and let me know what scenario fits your requirements best so that I could refine the answer.

Comment: Ya thanks a lot ,., but if i put 5phuhu any string after 5p then it wil not work ? .. instead as mentioned wanted to validate

Comment: I thought you wanted to only split those strings that end with `rk` or `bhk`. Do you want to just get *the first character in string must be digit and the second an alphabetic letter*? Then you'd have to either use `replaceAll("(?i)(?<=^\\d[a-z])", "")` or `Matcher` with `(?i)^\\d[a-z]` regex.